# Restrict generic extension method from extending strings

Tags: c#, methods, extension-methods

I have a very generic extension method to show any type of list within a console:

```
public static void ShowList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Values)
{
    foreach (T item in Values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Not when I have a `string` I can use this Method

```
string text = "test";
text.ShowList();
```

But in case of `string` it doesn't make sense in my application.

How can I exclude `string` from this method? I've read something about

```
ShowList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Values): Where != string //doesn't work
```

Comment: What aspect of `string` makes it inappropriate? Would you want `new List<char> { 'x', 'y', 'z' }.ShowList()` to work?

Comment: `char[]` yes / `string` no - since `typeof(string) == typeof(char[])` is false

Comment: Why? Both are sequences of characters. You need to think about what it is that makes string apparently "special" for you.

Comment: If `string` wouldn't be special, the type would not be introduced in C# and we would still work with `char[]` like in C++.

Comment: Oh it's special in various ways - but not in terms of whether or not it can be treated as a readable sequence of characters.

Comment: As an aside, I'd encourage you to follow .NET naming conventions - `Values` should be `values`. (You should probably validate that it's not null, too.)

Comment: Is this your actual code?  I think allowing `string` would make _more_ sense than for any other type...

Comment: @Toshi 1985's C++ called, they want their `char[]`s back ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This feels like a bit of an odd requirement to start with, to be honest - if something should work for any sequence of characters, then it should work for a string, which *is* a sequence of characters.

If you really want to make it fail to compile, you could add an overload accepting `string` which is marked as obsolete:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[Obsolete(IsError = true, Message = "A string is a sequence of characters, but is not intended to be shown as a list")]
public static void ShowList(this string text)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Overload resolution will pick that method, and then it'll fail to compile. The `EditorBrowsable` attribute will *hopefully* remove this from Intellisense - but you'll have to see whether that actually works. (It may show the other overload still, even though that wouldn't be picked.)

Another option would be to implement `ShowList<T>` as if the string was a single-entry list:

```
// Specialization to avoid listing each character separately.
public static void ShowList(this string text) => new[] { text }.ShowList();
```

In other words, make it valid to call, but handle it more appropriately.

Comment: after adding this to my code, the `ShowList` is still shown in auto completion. Is there a way to suppress this behaviour?

Comment: @Toshi: It's possible that `EditorBrowsable` would help - I've added that into my answer.

Comment: I'd rather go with a `NotSupportedException`, since this method not working is by-design and not because you didn't get around to implementing it.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Yes, that would probably be better - will edit.

Answer (score 9):

You can create another overload of `ShowList()` that is specific for `string` and mark it as `[Obsolete]`:

```
[Obsolete("Not intended for strings", true)]
public static void ShowList(this string val)
{
}
```

By passing `true` to the `IsError` parameter, the compiler will prevent you from using the method.

See [ObsoleteAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

For silent ignore you could use this:

```
public static void ShowList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Values)
{
    if (Values is String) return;
    // ...
}
```

Or if you want to also write the string:

```
public static void ShowList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Values)
{
    if (Values is String)
        Console.WriteLine(Values);
    else
        foreach (T item in Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
}
```

Comment: Note that this affects `"abc".AsEnumerable().ShowList()`. It's not clear what the OP would want or whether the OP gave this any consideration.

Comment: No, for my 2 methods that makes **no** difference:  `"abc".AsEnumerable()` just does `return source;` for everything that is already an `IEnumerable<T>`, and that includes strings. The method that gets called has signature `AsEnumerable<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)` and you can see its implementation here: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs (line 823 as we speak)

Comment: That's my point: you're picking the `Console.WriteLine(Values);` implementation because `Values is String` will be `true`, so you give it the special `string` treatment, even though the caller tried to bypass that special treatment. With the other answers that determine by the compile-time type which implementation to call, the `IEnumerable<char>` version would be used.